# Should I use the built in linter in Typescript >2 or TSLint?

Tags: typescript, lint

I'm trying to decide why I should use `TSLint` in my `Typescript2`/`Angular2` project.

List of rules exposed by `TSLint`: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/

Compiler options available using `TypeScript`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Since `Typescript2` now has some compiler options such as `--noUnusedParameters`, is there really a need for `TSLint`? Is `TSLint` a superset of the compiler options?

Project structure:

```
.
├── bower.json
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   └── app.module.ts
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.js
├── webpack.common.js
└── webpack.dev.config.js
```

Comment: Just use both..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TSLint removes rules when they are added to TypeScript proper. There's still *a lot* of rules in there that TypeScript doesn't check for, though, so if you care about it, you'll probably want to use both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happily using TSLint for [Typescript Library Starter](https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter) in combination with [TSLint config standard](https://github.com/blakeembrey/tslint-config-standard) which not only offers you a widen set of rules, but also they aim to be standardised.